# Coloring hyperlinks in table of contents

Tags: pandoc, quarto

Consider the following `quarto` code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
toc: true
---

# section 1

# section 2
```

The hyperlinks of the table of contents are all in black. Is there some way of making them, e.g., blue, to make more clear that the text is clickable?

Comment: Thanks, @KJ, for your comment. I believe that many people do not notice that the entries of the table of contents are clickable. In the case of web-pages, typically, the hyperlinks are easily identifiable, which does not happen with the table of contents of PDF documents generated by `quarto`.

Comment: Are you asking about `toccolor` pandoc variable in yaml?

Comment: Hi, @shafee, I would prefer that you answer, as the credits of the idea should go to you. As soon as you post your answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `toccolor` option in yaml to color the hyperlinks in table of contents,

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
toc: true
toccolor: blue
---

# section 1

# section 2
```

---

[image: colored toc]

---

Check out the [colors](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/pdf.html#colors) section from Quarto documentations for more related options such as, `linkcolor`, `citecolor`, `urlcolor` etc.